# context.active_object vs context.scene.objects.active

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, operator

Both `context.active_object` and `context.scene.objects.active` allow to get the active object in the scene. In most cases, they point to the same object.

However, now we have a case that inside an operator, `context.active_object` is `None`. Even tough, the active object get's just set before calling this operator, and after the operator has been called, `context.active_object` is the good value again.

I logged some values in the poll function of the operator and got the following results:

```
context.active_object:  None
bpy.context.active_object:  None
context.scene.objects.active:  <bpy_struct, Object("mask_defect_smooth")>
bpy.context.scene.objects.active:  <bpy_struct, Object("mask_defect_smooth")>
```

What is the difference between the 2 ways to acces the active object?
I have the same problem in at least v2.93 and v2.73.

Minimal addon to reproduce:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "basic_register",
    "description": "basic_register",
    "author": "XXX",
    "version": (1, 0),
#    "blender": (2, 73, 0),
    "blender": (2, 93, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh",
    "warning": "development",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244486/context-active-object-vs-context-scene-objects-active",
    "category": "Add Mesh"}

import bpy


class OBJECT_OT_log_active_object(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "log_active_object"
    bl_idname = "mesh." + bl_label
    bl_description = ""
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Execute: bpy.ops." + self.bl_idname.replace("MESH_OT_", "mesh.") + "()")
        print("active_object should also contain data:")
        print("context.active_object: ", context.active_object)
        print("bpy.context.active_object: ", bpy.context.active_object)
        print("context.view_layer.objects.active: ", context.view_layer.objects.active)
        print("bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active: ", bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active)
#        print("context.scene.objects.active: ", context.scene.objects.active)
#        print("bpy.context.scene.objects.active: ", bpy.context.scene.objects.active)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class OBJECT_OT_basic_register(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "basic_register"
    bl_idname = "mesh." + bl_label
    bl_description = ""
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Execute: bpy.ops." + self.bl_idname.replace("MESH_OT_", "mesh.") + "()")
        mask_defect_smooth = bpy.data.objects["mask_defect_smooth"]
        print("context.active_object: ", context.active_object)
        print("bpy.context.active_object: ", bpy.context.active_object)
        print("context.view_layer.objects.active: ", context.view_layer.objects.active)
        print("bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active: ", bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active)
#        print("context.scene.objects.active: ", context.scene.objects.active)
#        print("bpy.context.scene.objects.active: ", bpy.context.scene.objects.active)
#        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = mask_defect_smooth
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = mask_defect_smooth
        # bpy.context.scene.update()  # Does not help
        # Specifieng "EXEC_DEFAULT" or "INVOKE_DEFAULT" does not help too
        bpy.ops.mesh.log_active_object()
        return {'FINISHED'}


class OBJECT_OT_create_test_object(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "create_test_object"
    bl_idname = "mesh." + bl_label
    bl_description = ""
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Execute: bpy.ops." + self.bl_idname.replace("MESH_OT_", "mesh.") + "()")
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        ob = bpy.context.object
        ob.name = "mask_defect_smooth"
        ob.hide = True
        return {'FINISHED'}


class OBJECT_PT_MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "__ Panel __"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    bl_category = "wrapper"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("mesh.create_test_object")
        self.layout.operator("mesh.basic_register")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_log_active_object)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_create_test_object)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_basic_register)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_MyPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_log_active_object)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_create_test_object)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_basic_register)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_MyPanel)
```

Comment: The context is dynamically changed depending on what is going on under the hood, most likely your operator changed it and in doing so lost the link to the `active_object` (eg there is no active object when you scrub the timeline) whereas changing the context won't affect whether an object is selected in a particular scene / view layer (btw I assume you are using blender V2.79 or prior since from 2.8+ the syntax is `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active`). It's just a shortcut really since they point to the same object. But you should post a snippet of your code since it's hard to tell as is

Comment: Hey, I added a minimal addon to reproduce the problem. It seems that inside the addon, active_object can't be a hidden object, but in the Python console, it can be a hidden object. I got the same problem when porting the code to Blender 2.93